# Why are the results of Go and Rust serialization inconsistent？

Tags: go, rust, marshalling, serde-json

The results I want are as follows， but the result of Rust is another.

```
 [123 34 66 111 100 121 34 58 34 97 71 86 115 98 71 56 61 34 125]
```

golang sample:

```
type Response struct {
    Body    []byte
}
func Test_Marshal(t *testing.T)  {
    body := "hello"
    resp := &Response{
        Body:[]byte(body),
    }
    t.Log("resp:", resp)
    result, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
    t.Log("result: ", result)
}
```

go result:

```
    aa_test.go:17: resp: &{[104 101 108 108 111]}
    aa_test.go:19: result:  [123 34 66 111 100 121 34 58 34 97 71 86 115 98 71 56 61 34 125]
```

rust sample:

```
use serde_json::{Result, Value};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
pub struct Response {
    pub body: ::std::vec::Vec<u8>,
}

fn main() {
    let body_str = "hello".to_string();
    let resp = Response {
        body: Vec::from(body_str)
    };

    println!("resp: {:?}", resp);

    let result = serde_json::to_vec(&resp).unwrap();
    println!("result: {:?}",result)
}
```

rust result

```
resp: Response { body: [104, 101, 108, 108, 111] }
result: [123, 34, 98, 111, 100, 121, 34, 58, 91, 49, 48, 52, 44, 49, 48, 49, 44, 49, 48, 56, 44, 49, 48, 56, 44, 49, 49, 49, 93, 125]
```

Comment: The gonalg json contains a field called `Body`, and the rust contains a field called `body`. The difference is the capital `B` in the rust version.

Comment: But what are you reading and comparing JSON as bytes instead of string ? There's absolutely no guarantee that different serializers would have the same formatting even if you did have the same field names. If you want a strict binary format, use another serialization format.

Comment: Body or body, the result is the same

Comment: What's exactly your question ? What's "inconsistent" ? Are you comparing the two `result` byte arrays ? Did you expect them to be equal ? Why ?

Comment: Two background programs. The rust signs the response through np-256, and then golang needs to verify the signature of the response, so the [] bytes need to be equal.

Answer (score 5):

If we convert both your outputs from byte arrays to ASCII strings (I've used a simple Javascript code - `array.map(ch => String.fromCharCode(ch)).join("")`), we'll get the following:

```
// for Rust
{"body":[104,101,108,108,111]}
// for Go
{"Body":"aGVsbG8="}
```

So, there seem to be two differences:

- The first and the most obvious is the fields naming. Both serializers leave the field name in JSON as it was in the source code, so in Go it is `Body` (capitalized), while in Rust it is `body` (lower-case).
- The second is that Rust encodes the value as-is - i.e. the byte array is treated as a vector of numbers (it doesn't get any special treatment). In Go, however, it is converted to Base64 string - this is an [explicitly documented exception](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal), probably because in most cases this is the intended behavior.

---

Now, what to do here? It depends on what behavior you want to use. I don't know how to change output with Go, so I assume that it is correct, and the Rust one needs to be tweaked.

- To fix the key, you can simply annotate your field with [`serde::rename("Body")`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename).
- To fix the value, the simplest way is probably to use [`serde::serialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with) attribute together with [`base64` crate](https://lib.rs/crates/base64) - an example can be found [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/serialize-a-vec-u8-to-json-as-base64/57781):

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Response {
    #[serde(with="base64")]
    pub body: Vec<u8>,
}

mod base64 {
    use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
    use serde::{Deserializer, Serializer};

    pub fn serialize<S: Serializer>(v: &Vec<u8>, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let base64 = base64::encode(v);
        String::serialize(&base64, s)
    }
    
    pub fn deserialize<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<Vec<u8>, D::Error> {
        let base64 = String::deserialize(d)?;
        base64::decode(base64.as_bytes())
            .map_err(|e| serde::de::Error::custom(e))
    }
}
```

Comment: Through your method "#[serde (with =" Base64 ")]", it works. thank you